# Content-Length not in request but header is set... file wont open after download

Tags: javascript, php, download

I have the following code to download a file using XMLHttpRequest with a progress bar.

**EDIT:**

**The purpose is to demonstrate the difference between Gigabit speeds and common 10 Mbps connection. The user downloads a large video file on a mac all in one.**

**Progress bar shows on the page and file saves to disk in a couple of seconds... then user enables hardware switch to limit to 10Mbps and downloads again, this time most certainly aborting the transfer of the 330MB file.**

PHP (download.php):

```
<?
    $file='/path/to/some/video.mp4';

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onprogress=updateProgress;
req.open('GET', 'download', true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","video/mp4");
req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {  
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        ...
    }
};  
req.send();

function updateProgress (evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / 330581733);
    $('#downloadProgress').val(percentComplete);
    $('#progressVal').html(percentComplete.toString() + '%');
}
```

My request contains every header except the Content-Length which when $filsize is echoed... reads 330581733 (330MB and some change). My progress function uses the exact number for testing purposes but should be evt.total;

Part One: Why is the Content-Length header not available?

Part Two: Once the download is complete, why won't it open and where does it go?

Comment: youi can't download a file to the OS using just ajax. ajax fetches a string or blob or array buffer data. you can take that data and trigger a download yourself if you want. try http://danml.com/js/download.js to download a string to a named file in newer browsers.

Comment: I beg to differ... XMLHttpRequests can be used to retrieve the info and file system to then store to file on the clients hard drive. Chrome popped up a window and asked if I was ok with saving a large file to my disk so I'm on the right track.

Comment: XMLHttpRequests provide no access to the client's hard drive, unless you are running the page from a folder, in which case the browser often allows read-only access, but that doesn't help you save anything. if the file downloaded, it should be in the downloads menu. if it's not there, the file went to ram, perhaps backed by a temp file somewhere. since your server sets disposition, simply pass the video url to window.open(url) to download it. most browsers show a progress bar while it downloads.

Comment: I never said XMLHttpRequest could save, hence the reference to the filesystem to store the data. Saving is very well possible and the issue I was having was the blob itself does not go anywhere without calling the navigator storage library. I thought req.open() would do that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont typically answer my own questions but since everyone is saying this impossible, I'd like to prove you all wrong...

First you need to reference from your script... [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.storageInfo = window.storageInfo || window.webkitStorageInfo;

// Request access to the file system for persistent storage of up to 1GB (1024^3)
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (1024*1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
    console.log ('requestQuota: ', arguments); // FOR DEBUGGING
    window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, function(fs) {
        console.log ('fs: ', arguments); // FOR DEBUGGING
    }, errorHandler);
}, errorHandler);

req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
req.onprogress=updateProgress;
req.open('GET', '/path/to/php/download', true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","video/mp4");
req.responseType = "blob";
req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {  
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        saveAs(req.response, "filename.mp4"); // DEFINED IN FileSaver.js
    }
}
req.send(null);

// PROGRESS BAR UPDATE
function updateProgress (evt) {
    var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
    $('#downloadProgress').val(percentComplete);
}
```

This will allow progress bar on page and will save to local downloads directory.

NOTE: Only works in Chrome so far.
Version tested: 30.0.1599.101 (Win 7)

Chrome will display a message asking if the client is OK with saving large files to disk upon loading the page with the storage request.

Also worth noting that the Content-Length still does not appear in the request and evt.total in updateProgress has been replaced with static file size.

Comment: it was just me that says you can't, and i standby that statement. the FileSaver.js script basically does the same thing as the link i posted earlier...

Comment: The script you referenced earlier does NOT do the same thing as FileSaver.js and will not work with what I'm trying to accomplish but thanks anyway. The script written above in the answer works for what I need so no point in arguing... BUT... placing a frame on the page with the data or clicking a generated a tag is not the same as using the File System to store the already downloaded data. The blob is also already generated by the XMLHttpRequest as well as the reference to MSBlobBuilder wont work because we're using a mac for the demo, hence no IE 10+. (not mentioned previously)

Comment: a think a few simple typos made this more confusing than need be. glad you found something. i probably should add blobs to my download script. filesaver.js uses window instead of a frame, and they both use <a download> first if available. aside: are you sure chrome uses the filewriter branch? i thought that was behind a permissions wall...

Comment: Chrome allows navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota to request the storage space as permanent, but in doing so, alerts the user that the browser is attempting to save a large file to the disk... not sure if it alerts for smaller files though and since our purpose is to showcase Gigabit speeds for large file downloads, I will not be testing. I do know that once the user accepts the request for the large download 1 time, as long as the space requested is the same in subsequent requests, it will not ask again. Also works in Chrome for mac Version: 30.0.1599.101

Comment: Also turns out that the `window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, function(fs) {
        console.log ('fs: ', arguments); // FOR DEBUGGING
    }, errorHandler);` line is redundant and deprecated and it works without it